# The limit inferior and superior of any sequence of independent r.v.s is almost surely a constant

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $A_1,A_2,\dots$ be a sequence of independent random variables. Isn't it true that $\lim \inf$ and $\lim \sup$ of the sequence $\left(A_n\right)_{n=1}^\infty$ is almost surely a constant? My reasoning is that since we know that both $\lim\inf$ and $\lim\sup$ are tail sigma-algebra measurable, and the $\lim\inf$ and $\lim\sup$ of $\left(A_n\right)_{n=1}^\infty$ are themselves random variables, it then follows from the Kolmogoro's zero-one law that lim sup/lim  inf are almost surely constants.

Comment: @Karl What results there are regarding the CDF/PDF of lim sup/inf? How could you prove the claim you stated?

Comment: Kolmogorov's $0$-$1$ law considers constants in $\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right, so long as your constants can be $\pm \infty$. Focusing on the $\limsup$ part, you can obtain a slightly more direct proof than Kolmogorov 0-1 with the following:

**Lemma**: If $M$ is such that $\sum \mathbb P(A_i > M) < \infty$, then $\limsup A_i \leq M$ almost surely. Conversely, if $M$ is such that $\sum \mathbb P(A_i > M) = \infty$, then $\limsup A_i \geq M$ almost surely.

Both proofs are straightforward Borel-Cantelli applications. For a fixed $i$, the expression $\mathbb P(A_i > M)$ is nonincreasing in $M$, so if we define $M^* := \sup \{M \colon \sum \mathbb P(A_i > M) = \infty\}$ it follows that $\limsup A_i = M^*$ almost surely.

**EDIT**: In my original answer, I had mistakenly assumed that the variables were identically distributed. Thanks to Karl for (kindly!) pointing out my mistake.

Comment: I had a direct approach like this in mind, but I'm not sure it works. When you say $M$ is such that $\Bbb P(A_i > M) = 0$, do you mean for all $i$, or for infinitely many $i$, or what? I also made the same claim about the suprema of the supports, but I think a counterexample is $A_i\sim Bernoulli(1/2^i)$.

Comment: For $A_i\sim Bernoulli(1/2^i)$, the probability that infinitely many $A_i=1$ is zero by Borel-Cantelli, so $\lim\sup A_i=0$ with probability 1 even though all the supports include 1.

Comment: @Karl Ah -- I misread the original question as to indicate that the variables were i.i.d. You're quite right, and thanks for the catch. I'll ponder what this does.

Comment: @Karl I think I've fixed it, but hopefully I haven't made any *new* mistakes....